# magento change base_url with subdirectories

Tags: magento-1.8, url, url-rewrite, base-url, apache2

I have 2 websites - main ***www.mainwebsite.com*** with product presentation
and shop based on magento, url - ***shop.mainwebsite.com***.
now I need to change shops url to ***www.mainwebsite.com/shop/***.
but after changing magento base_url to ***www.mainwebsite.com/shop/*** I always get **404**, because it searching site resources into shop directory which is not exists.

So do I need to change something else in magento or look inside apache configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing you need to edit *.htaccess*

Replace

```
RewriteBase /
```

with

```
RewriteBase /shop/
```

Next go to apache config and point *www.mainwebsite.com* to parent directory of /*shop*/ dir